# hide ipad keyboard on tap outside of input

Tags: jquery, ipad, focus

I am trying to work out how to close the keyboard when a user touches outside an input. I have tried lots of things with no joy.

www.bbc.co.uk does it really well but cant see where its done?

```
$("input").focus(); works but if I do a body on click function it never shows.
```

How could I do this effectively?

Comment: Did you figure this out?